# Does not work the filter "embed_oembed_html"

Tags: wordpress, iframe, filter, youtube

I'm using the embed_oembed_html filter to be able to lock a YouTube iframe and do it responsive, but this does not work. Some clue ?

My function:

```
function embed_html_vanellope($html, $url, $attr){
    return '<div class="video-container">' . $html . '</div>';
}
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'embed_html_vanellope', 10, 3);
```

Thanks

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50779/how-to-wrap-oembed-embedded-video-in-div-tags-inside-the-content

Comment: @Christina don´t work ! :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jetpack, it overides this shortcode and you have to use instead.

```
add_filter('video_embed_html', 'embed_html_vanellope');
```

Comment: If you're using Jetpack:
Goto /wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules and disable shortcodes module